# Java sort list and then take sublist from list using Stream api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
public class Result {
  ...
  private Integer averageRating;
}
```

I have a list of result `List<Result>`. I want to sort them by `averageRating` and then want to get form a specific index to a specific index like 10 to 20.

I can do that using `Collection.sort()` using `Comparator.comparing()` then take sublist from list. But problem is higher index may be greater than the list size, that's why I have to manually  handle that. Like 10 to 20 but list size is 15 then 5 items will be output.

But how can I do that using Java Stream API ?

I tried something but not worked:

```
List<Result> result = list.stream().sorted(e -> e.getAverageRating()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Instead of `.sorted(e -> e.getAverageRating())` you should use `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getAverageRating()))`. and not sure why you couldn't take a `subList` after stream operation when you already knew how to do that.

Comment: @Naman I updated the question `But problem is higher index may be greater than the list size, that's why I have to manually handle that.` new part

Comment: If the values could be higher than the list size and you are not `filter`ing elements from the list in `stream` pipeline, you can perform `.subList(startIndex, higherIndex > list.size() ? list.size() : higherIndex)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
int from = 10;
int to = 20;

List<Result> result = list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Result::getAverageRating))
    .skip(from)
    .limit(to - from)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It should skip the first 10 elements of the sorted stream, then take not more than the difference of the range specified.

Comment: `.limit(higherIndex-lowerIndex)`